# Is there any solution regarding first screen loading in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

When I run my app in physical and or virtual device during the installation of app android studio warns that the Skipped 533 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread How to resolve it.

Comment: You can resolve this by doing less work on the main thread. We might be able to assist you with it, if you show us what it is that your code does. Without any code, there is little we can do.

Comment: Currently I'm learning flutter that's why I don't know how I can include all the UI related work in worker thread?? Need solution.

Comment: We cannot give you a solution, as long as you don't show us your problem. Without a *specific* problem (including code), we can only give you generic advice like "read a good book" or "follow your class".

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to debug mode. Not just the app is loaded, also everything required to debug is being instantiated. When you create a release version, does the same behavior occur?

Comment: yes...and also my the first screen loads very slow even in my physical device is this flutter theme style or due UI loading in main thread